# Discord music bot issue

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm making a discord bot for my server and I'm having some issues with my music code!
The code is located [here](https://hastebin.com/opiyobicih.js).

When I run the bot it works well, but when I do the `!play` command it throws the following error:

`Error: FFMPEG not found`

If someone could help me, I would be thankful. Thank you for your time.

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
if (msg.author.bot) return undefined;
if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return undefined;
const args = msg.content.split(' ');

if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
    const voiceChannel = msg.member.voiceChannel;
    if (!voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('Tens de estár numa sala para eu poder entrar!');
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(msg.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) {
        return msg.channel.send('Só podes tocar musica no canal de Musica!')
    }
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
        return msg.channel.send('Não posso tocar musica nesse canal!')
    }

    try {
        var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Não consigo entrar no canal porque: ${error}`);
        return msg.channel.send(`Não consigo entrar no canal de voz: ${error}`);
    }

    const dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(args[1]))
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('Acabou a musica');
            voiceChannel.leave();
        })
        .on('error', error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(5 / 5);

} else if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
    if (msg.member.voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('Não estás no canal');
    msg.member.voiceChannel.leave();
    return undefined;
}
});

client.login(token);`
```

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg installed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not installed ffmpeg.

You can find an easy tutorial on how to install and add ffmpeg to path here:

https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows

After you have installed ffmpeg, it will also need to be installed with npm like so:

```
npm install ffmpeg
```